# scala: why is 1/0 an arithmetic exception but 1.0/0.0 = Double.Infinity

Tags: java, scala

It seems inconsistent that in Scala, integer arithmetic div by zero throws a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`, but floating point arithmetic (`1.0/0.0`) returns `Double.Infinity`.

I understand that from a type perspective it might be tricky to have both a Double.Infinity and an Integer.Infinity, but I assume with scala's powerful type system they could have figured out some other way to resolve that aspect of the problem.

Is there something else I'm missing that would better explain these two differing behaviors?

Comment: This behavior results from the JVM, not anything specific to Scala.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a hardware limitation, not a software one, and the reason is simple: IEEE754 floating point arithmetic explicitly supports `+Inf` and `-Inf`, i.e. there are bit representations that correspond to those two ideas, and therefore it makes sense for them to be the result of `1.0/0.0`.

Integer arithmetic as implemented in common processors does not have an internal representation for infinities, and therefore has to throw an error.

You could implement an integral type that supports infinities in software, but it would be slower as a division operation would not correspond directly to the processor
's `div` instruction. This is not sensible in my opinion: Integer div-by-zero errors are *almost always* due to (a) incorrect implementation of your algorithm or (b) failure to validate user input correctly, both of which are fundamental problems that have to be tackled before you compile your code, not at runtime via exceptions! In FP arithmetic on the other hand, you may easily run into div-by-zero when you don't (and really cannot) expect it: `1e-308/1e+308` has a correct value, but it is not representable as a `double` even though both operands are.

Comment: You say "it would be slower". Yes, if you needed a check for zero *before* each division. But couldn't you just divide normally, and then catch any exceptions? (I don't know scala at all.)

Comment: Like you, I have no idea whether a `try-catch` block that doesn't catch an exception incurs a lot of overhead in scala. The more important problem is that you need to box your types once again if you want to propagate the infinities - which may not be a good idea at all since *they should not happen in integer arithmetic*. I'll add a paragraph on why this is above.

Comment: @Joseph I've added a paragraph explaining why I think that int-div-by-0 should always be an error while it makes sense to treat float-div-by-zero differently.

Comment: My comment is probably wrong. I had been thinking that a software exception here would start life as a hardware exception (ie trap) to the `div` instruction, and so any additional overhead would be nil. But you still need the equivalent of `setjmp()` for the `try`.

Comment: Actually, entering a try block should (on any decent jvm) be free. There is no need for a setjmp call, all you need to do when an exception is thrown is to walk up the call stack, retrieve the instruction pointer for each frame, use it to get the information record for the corresponding method (I'm assuming the code is jitted here, this would be direct if we're in interpreted mode) and check if the instruction pointer is inside any catch block of the method. All the work happens at throw time, entering the try block incurs no penalty (normal execution already requires to maintain a call stack)

Comment: As for the overhead of boxing, it can be eliminated using scala 2.10 value classes. So in the end, the real cost of implemeting it in software is that of always checking against 0 before dividing. Which is a high cost indeed.